# Alternative to like/ like any?... regexp?

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I have a TERADATA dataset that resembles the below:

```
Customer_ID | Targeting_Region

    12      | targ=EU, targ=!Eu.Fr

    34      | targ=Asia

    56      | targ=!EU
```

The '!' denotes 'does not equal'. For example, the customer in Row #1 wants to target the EU, but exclude France.

I want to create a field that flags (with a '1') any row where there is 'positive' targeting. By 'positive' targeting I am referring to any row where a specific region as been explicitly INCLUDED ('negative' targeting would be where a region is explicity EXCLUDED, such as the exclusion of France in Row #1). For example, Row #1 contains both positive and negative targeting, Row #2 contains only positive targeting, Row #3 contains only negative targeting.

The problem I am encountering is that a simple case statement won't work (as far as I can tell). I have tried the 2 statements below:

```
(case when targeting_region like '%targ=%'; then 1 else 0 end) as target_flag

(case when ((targeting_region like '%targ=%';) and (targeting_region not like '%targ=!%';)) then 1 else 0 end) as target_flag
```

The 1st statement above doesn't work because it will return 1 for both 'targ=' and 'targ=!

The 2nd statement above doesn't work because it will return 1 for rows that ONLY have positive targeting. As such, Row #1 (above) would return a 0 (I want it to return a 1)

Note that that value following 'targ=' could also be a number. E.g., 'targ=12345'

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this? I have heard that teradata has something called regexp but I have been unable to find a good explanation of it after quite a bit of searching.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but if you want a 1 only when there is a positive target and no negative target, then why not make it 0 if there exists a negative target and 1 otherwise?

For example,

```
case when targeting_region like '%targ=!%' then 0
when targeting_region like '%targ=%' then 1
else null -- Optional if you want to handle when no targeting regions exist
end as target_flag
```

Comment: The issue I am having is that certain rows will have both a positive and negative target. E.g., see Row #1 in my original post. A row such as this one would return 0 with your code, whereas I need it to return 1.

Thanks for the response, though!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

(case when REGEXP_INSTR(targeting_region,'targ=[A-Z,a-z]') = 0; then 0 else 1)

I found syntax and example of REGEXP_INSTR() at
http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Regular_Expr_Functions.085.03.html#ww14955402

Because there was too little info at this site, you will have to fiddle with it to get it to work.

For example...

The equal sign in "...targ=...", and maybe even the left and right brackets, may need to be escaped, perhaps with backslash. Also, the above assumes that if there is no match, the function returns 0 (rather than NULL).  It may need to be changed from "=0" to "IS NULL".  Also, I assume that the parameters after the first two are optional.  You may need to specify them, e.g., "1,1,i".  Also, the expression could be simplified a bit, for example by using a shortcut for [A-Z,a-z], if you can find better documentation.

Explanation:
The second parameter specifies a "pattern" to look for in the first parameter.
1. "targ=" looks for exactly those characters.
2. "[A-Z,a-z]" looks for an alphabetic character.  If a "!" occurs, it will not match and the search will proceed with the rest of the string.
3. REGEXP_SUBSTR() returns the character position where the pattern was found in the string.  That's overkill because you only want to know yes it was found or no it was not, but hopefully it works because I couldn't find a simpler function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want **1** if there's any included target regardless of additional excluded regions?

This searches for 'targ=' followed by any other character than '!':

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(Targeting_Region,'targ=[^!]') = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

If your release doesn't include REGEXP function there might be OREPLACE:

```
CASE WHEN POSITION('targ=' IN OREPLACE (Targeting_Region, 'targ=!', '')) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```